# how ot extract <pre> or white-space: pre-wrap; content correctly with jsoup

Tags: jsoup

somehow all whitespace chars (pre tag or css white-space: pre-wrap;) are removed by jsoup.
how can I retrieve the raw html text with jsoup ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't, well not with the latest available `(1.6.1)`. jSoup just beautifies the html. Although you can retrieve the complete text node using the `getWholeText()` API of `TextNode` class.